# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver what to do?

Tags: java, mysql-connector

I am getting this when i try to launch our java server:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

But i have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar  in the same folder where the script is, and making this when i run the script:

```
   java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar  -jar AvatarServer.jar
```

But still getting this. What to do? I am using af CentOS server.

```
 root@host [/home/nagoom/Server_Example]# java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar       -jar AvatarServer.jar
 ************************
  **  FIRING UP SERVER! **
  ************************
   Running MySQLChatMessageSaver
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at items.ItemsDatabase.DownloadData(ItemsDatabase.java:35)
at items.ItemsDatabase.InitializeData(ItemsDatabase.java:24)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:84)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at gameInstances.RoomController.DownloadRoomData(RoomController.java:46)
at gameInstances.RoomController.InitializeRooms(RoomController.java:32)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:85)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at gameInstances.RoomController.LoadLockedSeatsForAll(RoomController.java:121)
at gameInstances.RoomController.InitializeRooms(RoomController.java:33)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:85)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at gameInstances.RoomController.DownloadApartmentData(RoomController.java:89)
at gameInstances.RoomController.InitializeRooms(RoomController.java:34)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:85)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at gameInstances.RoomController.LoadItemsForAllRooms(RoomController.java:160)
at gameInstances.RoomController.InitializeRooms(RoomController.java:35)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:85)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at clothes.ClothesDatabase.DownloadGraphicsData(ClothesDatabase.java:42)
at clothes.ClothesDatabase.InitializeGraphics(ClothesDatabase.java:31)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:86)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
      MySQL exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     MySQL exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at moods.MoodsDatabase.DownloadData(MoodsDatabase.java:29)
at moods.MoodsDatabase.InitializeData(MoodsDatabase.java:16)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:89)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at robots.RobotHandler.downloadBots(RobotHandler.java:31)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:90)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at levels.LevelDatabase.DownloadData(LevelDatabase.java:21)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:91)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at database.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:13)
at network.SocketHandler.resetOnlineStatuses(SocketHandler.java:172)
at network.SocketHandler.startListening(SocketHandler.java:93)
at server.AvatarServer.run(AvatarServer.java:44)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` to class-path in **MANIFEST.MF** file in `AvatarServer.jar`. Example:

```
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

`-jar` and `-cp` are mutually exclusive. `-jar` says: the classpath is the following jar, and all the libraries referenced in its manifest file. So you must use:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;AvatarServer.jar com.foo.bar.AvatarMainClass
```

or, if you want to run your app with `-jar`, reference the mysql driver jar in the jar's manifest file, as explained in [the jar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Comment: Your example doesn't work. I am not Java familiar. It's a java source from my earlier programmer. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Define "does not work". You didn't use the class name `com.foo.bar.AvatarMainClass` literally, did you? If so, of course you must replace this class name with the actual main class you want to launch. The one that is referenced in the manifest file of the jar.